# The matrix equation for solving a straight line

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, least-squares

So, I'm looking at [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.4686v1.pdf) and trying to understand where equation 5 comes from.

Looking at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#The_general_problem), I see that they would use $\mathbf{X} = (\mathbf{A^T}\mathbf{A})^{-1}\mathbf{A^T}\mathbf{y}$ which is equivalent to $\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{A^{-1}}\mathbf{y}$. These equations give the same answer so why bother with the more complex one? Is this a generalisation to higher order? If so, why? I've seen vague references to reducing dimensionality.

From the above equations I can see that the covariance matrix is introduced to weight the above and form equation 5 in the paper. But how does it end up in the middle. And while I'm at it, why the inverse of the covariance matrix?

(It's been a while since I used matrices and linear algebra)

Thanks

Comment: What if $A^{-1}$ doesn't make sense? For example, when the matrix is not square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the text surrounding equation (6):

> It can be justified in several ways; the linear algebra justification starts by noting that you want to solve the equation 
>   $$
> \mathbf Y = \mathbf A \mathbf X
> $$
>   but you can't because that equation is *overconstrained*.

In particular, we generally have that $A$ is $m \times n$ with $m > n$.  In general, it might be impossible to solve $y = Ax$, depending on your choice of $y$.  If, however, we consider the *least squares* problem, we'll always have a solution (that is, at least one solution).  Moreover (assuming the columns of $A$ are linearly independent), we'll always have a *formula* for the solution given a vector $y$, which is even better.

Comment: Great thanks. So why does the covariance matrix appear on both sides of the equation? If it's there to add some uncertainty tolerance, why is it $A^TC^{-1} AX = A^TC^{-1} Y$?

Comment: The covariance matrix has an important role in the least squares problem. In particular, note that $(Cx)\cdot x= \|Ax\|^2$.

Answer (score 0):

If the matrix $A$ is not a square matrix then it has not an inverse. In this case note that $A^TA$ is square matrix ( called the [Gramian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix)) and, if the column (or row) vectors of $a$ are linearly independent that this matrix is invertible. So we can find:
$$
Ax=y \Rightarrow A^TAx=Ay \Rightarrow x=(A^TA)^{-1}Ay
$$